# How do I best organise multiple projects in GIT?

Tags: git, version-control

I'm elaluating whether GIT is possible to organise our projects.
We are working under Windows with Visual Studio 2010 on a local network.

Our project organisation is as follows:

We have a shared code base (call it SHARE) where all developers are allowed to extend, modify and do bug fixes.
All developers have multiple private projects which depend on thes shared code base.
So the structure is:

```
root
   |
   +-- SHARE
   +-- Project 1 Dev 1
   +-- Project 2 Dev 1
   +-- Project 1 Dev 2
```

What I think of is one origin Repository on a network drive with clones on every developer PC and 1 private Repository for each project on the developer PCs (maybe some backup on network as well). Good would be some kind of link, so that when a developer checks out his project he will get the correct shared source as well.
Is this possible with GIT and how?

Or can you recommend a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Good would be some kind of link, so
>   that when a developer checks out his
>   project he will get the correct shared
>   source as well. Is this possible with
>   GIT and how?

[Submodules](http://progit.org/book/ch6-6.html) is probably what you're after -- they let you store a "pointer" to some other repo inside a main one (the "superproject") with metadata about the exact "state" of the subproject so everyone is working against a consistent shared subproject.

The submodule itself can be worked on and improved just like any other repository, and the "state" pointer can be updated to the newly agreed upon version whenever is appropriate.

So your superproject would contain one submodule: "shared", and when devs clone your main repo, they run `git submodule init && git submodule update` to automatically get their submodules set up as necessary.

Comment: Just to check whether I get you.
There is one repo on network for SHARE.
And for every developer project there is a local repo, which has SHARE as a submodule?
Ok, I try to set it up this way.

Comment: I tried to set this up with Git Extensions and found a problem. Maybe you can help me. I have now one repo called test and one repo called SHARE. If I try to add the submodule SHARE to the project test, Git always wants to copy all files from SHARE to test\SHARE. But I don't want them to be copied.